# Best practice for executing parameterised queries in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, parameterized-query

Ok, so I have easily 100-200 queries on my website now, all parameterised.

Here's an example of one of them:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db_name');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `x` FROM `y` WHERE `z` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $test);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->close();

$mysqli->close();
```

So my question is, what is the best practice for opening/closing the connection to the database?

Is it best to leave the connection open, run multiple queries and then close the connection at the end of the page. Like so:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db_name');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `a` FROM `b` WHERE `c` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $test1);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->close();

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `x` FROM `y` WHERE `z` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $test2);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->close();

$mysqli->close();
```

Or is it best to open the connection before each query, and then close immediately afterwards? Like so:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db_name');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `a` FROM `b` WHERE `c` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $test1);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->close();

$mysqli->close();


$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db_name');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `x` FROM `y` WHERE `z` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $test2);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->close();

$mysqli->close();
```

Currently I open the connection before the page opening `<html>` tag and then close it just after the closing `</html>` tag. Is this safe/good practice?

Comment: By the way, all this stuff has nothing to do with parameterized queries but rather with queries in general

Comment: @YourCommonSense I realise that, however last time I posted a question on this site - yourself in fact had a go at me for not using parameterised queries. Posting my question in this way was to ensure that the question was productive and any comments weren't side-tracked by going into the pro's & con's of parameterised queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening and closing the connection takes resources, so the goal would be to open/close the connection as few times as possible, thereby executing as many queries as possible while a single connection is open.

Whether this means opening the connection when the script starts and closing it when it finishes, or opening/closing for each query, is going to depend on the nature of your application.

For instance, if most of your scripts have one or more queries, then opening/closing the connection and the beginning and end of the script is going to be best.  If, on the other hand, most of your scripts are query-less, then establishing the connection when you want to execute a query is going to be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it best to leave the connection open, run multiple queries and then close the connection at the end of the page.

Yes.

> Or is it best to open the connection before each query, and then close immediately afterwards?

No.

> Currently I open the connection before the page opening  tag and then close it just after the closing . Is this safe/good practice?

No.
Your application have to be structured such a way to let connection to be closed painlessly before the page opening `<head>` tag, because **all** the database interaction have to be finished before any output started.

> Best practice for executing parameterized queries in PHP?

To create a function of course, to make execution in one line instead of ten (and to handle all this opening/closing stuff), like this

```
$data = $db->get("SELECT `a` FROM `b` WHERE `c` = ?", $test1);
```

Comment: Why does the connection have to be closed before `<head>`?

Comment: It is not necessarily have to be closed, but every database interaction apparently have to be finished before the page opening <head> tag.

Comment: I've never known of such a requirement — can you cite a source for it?

Comment: Oh, just read something on *business logic from display logic separation*. I have no link at hand as I find the principle quite logical by itself, but I am sure it is easy googleable too. In short, no output should be started before all data got ready.

Comment: I understand that it's good practice to separate such things, but it's wrong to say that connections “have to be closed before […] `<head>`” when, in fact, they don't. Perhaps “have to” should be changed to “should”.

Comment: Well, I have to agree it is bad phrasing but I take it as a some sort of pun, using the OP's literal wording to emphasize the contradiction. The idea was to tell that there should be no relation  between database connection and opening/closing tags, as implied by the OP. I'll try to rephrase to something less ambiguous.